# Python application using external library written in C++ with multiple threads

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, boost

I have a library written in C++ that uses heavily threads for background processing. This library API is called from Python using boost-python bindings. However, it seems that threads external to Python don't run anymore. One external thread, that does processing inside an infinite loop with Sleep() function, never leaves Sleep() anymore after one or several iterations. I know that Python has GIL for controlling the way the threads are run, but could someone explain why external threads, that don't access Python objects are so heavily disturbed by Python ? Is there a solution for this without changing too much the external library ?

thanks

Bogdan

Comment: Crystal balls are rare, you will have to be much more precise in your description than this. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I have some working code in what might be a similar library.  How do you start the background threads?